# Extremal problem with infinite cardinals

Tags: combinatorics, infinitary-combinatorics

Made up, but somewhat interesting:

Let $\lambda\leq\kappa$ be infinite cardinals. Let $X$ be a set of cardinality $\kappa$.

Let $F\subseteq [X]^\kappa$ be a family of $2^\kappa$ subsets, which is closed under taking intersections of $\lambda$-many members.

Let $E\subseteq F$ have the property that for each $f\in F$ there is $e\in E$ with $e\subseteq f$.

How small can $E$ be in general?